# In google app engine, how to check if a model is empty or not?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have a model called "Customer" in google app engine with python:

```
class Customer(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    age = db.IntegerProperty()
```

before I create any instance/object of the Customer model, I would like to check if the model is empty(no object has been created), I tried something in Python like:

```
 customers = Customer.all()
 for customer in customers:
    if customer:
       logging.info("there is customer in Customer Model!")
    else:
       logging.info("The Customer Model is empty!")
 ........
```

when there is no instance/object in Customer model, "customers" in above snippet is not "None", while the line "for customer in customers:" always jumps out(means there is nothing in "customers"?), any idea? in addition, can I check this in Django template?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use count()

```
 customers = Customer.all()  
 if customers.count(1):
    # do something
```

Comment: thanks aschmid00, it works. customers.count() returns int 0 (False) when no instance in the Customer model that can be use to check if the model is empty.

Comment: @cnherald use count(1) to save some cycles

Comment: Hi Shay, how to use count(1) instead of count(), any difference?

Comment: @cnherald using count(1) (passing 1 as param) with execute the count query but will return if it reaches 1 if you don't do that and you have a lot of entities in the datastore it will continue till 1000.

Answer (score 1):

-- **EDIT: DON'T USE THIS CODE** --
This code is slower than using count(1), I'm leaving this a bad reference.

---

```
customers = Customer.all().get()
if customer:
  logging.info("there is customer in Customer Model!")
else:
  logging.info("The Customer Model is empty!")
```

Comment: nice one, it works as well. can you please explain what does Customer.all().get() return? thanks.

Comment: @cnherald it execute the query and return the first result

Comment: This will be slower than `.count(1)`.

Comment: @NickJohnson thanks, make sense because it needs to return an entity, while count(1) returns an int.